# How to display error message from DataAnnotationsExtensions instead of DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have in my viewmodel something like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

namespace Project.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class AddViewModel
    {
        [Integer(ErrorMessage="ID must be an integer.")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I run the program, the error message displayed would be "The field ID must be a number." which I think is from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations . How do I display the error message I created using DataAnnotationsExtensions instead? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this property in Global file

```
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```